# Heat transfer in solidification of cylindrical billet

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, computational-physics

I am trying to plot IN[image] MATLAB the temperature profile of solidification of metal in manufacture of cylindrical billets.
The metal is solidifying and the billet moves downwards as a constant water curtain flows on the outer surface.
So the velocity component is only in the z-direction.
Apart from the Fourier-Kirschoff equation for energy balance with the appropriate boundary conditions, I figured I would need to write the continuity Navier-Stokes equation for fluid flow as well.

But this makes continuity equation as $\dfrac{du}{dz} = 0$ , which I already know. So do I really need this equation?
Also I am left with only one Navier-stokes euqation in z direction that on integration would give Pressure $P = \text{density}\cdot g\cdot z$

Do I need to model flow at all?

EDIT: I have added the image.

Further explanation of question:
Liquid metal is added from the top. The water jets hit the outer surface of the metal and start solidifying it. The cylinder moves downwards and the water curtain flows around it.

Comment: Are you assuming the water's temperature to be constant?

Comment: No,there is no assumption of constant water temperature. I am assuming a constant flow rate of water and known inlet temperature.

Comment: Well, good luck modelling that. At least with a high flow rate one can assume a constant temp. at the boundary. Now you're modelling a complicated heat exchanger with phase transition on one side.

Comment: Are you asking if water flow in the curtain needs to be modeled?

Comment: No, my question does not pertain to the water curtain. What I meant was do I have to simultaneously solve partial differential equations for mass, momentum & energy? Or the one for energy alone?

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't have to write flow equations for solid part of the billet (sounds like a trivial statement), but you will have to take into account vertical velocity $u_z$ of solid billet while solving energy equation. Under certain conditions you may neglect this as well and treat the problem as one of pure conduction to a good approximation. This happens when heat transfer in vertical direction along solid billet due to motion of billet is negligible in comparison with heat transfer in that direction due to conduction. For this you will need low value of $u_z$ and high value of thermal diffusivity $\alpha$; in particular Peclet number, $Pe\equiv \frac{u_zL}{\alpha}$ has to be small. $L$ is some length scale relevant to the problem at hand, such as billet diameter or billet length. If length of solid billet is large so that temperature within the billet becomes constant with $z$ well before the billet end, then you may take billet diameter as your length scale. If $Pe$ number is small you wouldn't err much if you obtained your temperature profile by treating it as a conduction problem, with appropriate boundary conditions of course.